# Restart multiple Azure VMSS with time shedule with Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machines

I have multiple windows and Linux VMSS machines in azure, I need to recreate the pods, particularly with the windows machine after **x** days of creation.

I need to implement it with help of Powershell script.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Restart-AzVmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/restart-azvmss?view=azps-8.3.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404) command to restart a scale set.